# A simple blocking alert and confirm dialog

Tags: javascript, dialog, alert, confirm

I just want to find a simple blocking confirm dialog - the default one is too ugly:

```
if (SomeConfirm("Are you sure?", "Yes", "No) == 'Yes') {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

I did see multiple jAlert/jConfirm versions - none of them works on my ASP.NET MVC project.

I tried Bootstrap modal, but it is not blocking. While the dialog is shown, all the code that is after the dialog have been executed. This is not what I wanted.

Answer (score -1):

You can't, cross-browser, it's just not a feature that's provided.

The solution is to stop trying to use blocking UI and instead embrace the asynchronous nature of web programming. It's really not at all difficult to do

```
someNiftyConfirm(message, function() {
    doThis();
    doThat();
});
```

instead of

```
if (confirm(message)) {
    doThis();
    doThat();
}
```

Comment: *(Realized as I was finishing the above that **of course** this is a duplicate question. Found a dupe target, deleted the answer, but then decided to leave it but make it a CW.)*